# regex escape double question mark

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, escaping

I have a social networking site,every thing is working fine,my only problem is whenever i enter double question mark in review or comment field it shows weird text.

==========

If i entered "hello??"
it printed out like this "hellojQuery110205576835575724747_1411410901236",
i want to know how to escape special characters,in my case double question mark.
Is there any better way to do this without Regular expression.
Thanks in advance.
this is my code.

```
$(document).undelegate('.comment', 'keypress').delegate('.comment', 'keypress', function(e) {

                if ($.trim($(this).val()) !== '') {
                    if (e.which === 10 || e.which === 13) {
                        var comment = $(this).val();
                        var id = $(this).closest('.review_list').attr('id');
                        $.ajax({
                            type: 'POST',
                            url: '../controller/pageController.php',
                            data: 'review_id=' + id + '&comment=' + comment + '&luser_id=' + luser_id,
                            dataType:'json',
                            cache: false,
                            success: function(id) {
                                if($.trim(id)=='NO'){
                                 window.location='profile.php'; 
                                                     }
                                id = $.trim(id.id);
                                var c = "<li id='" + id + "'><div id='c_thumb'>"+(thumb != null ? '<img src="profile_images/' + thumb + '"/>' : '')+"</div><div id='commenter'><a href='userprofile.php?id="+luser_id+"'>" + name + "</a></div><div id='time'> 0 second ago</div><p>" + comment + "</p><a id='c_remove' href=''>remove</a></li>";

                                $('#comment_box li:last-child').before(c);
                                document.getElementById("post_comment").reset();
                            }//end of success
                        });

                    }
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to encode URL parameters properly. One way is to call `encodeURIComponent()` on each parameter, but since you're using jQuery I recommend letting it do the encoding for you, by providing an object as the `data:` option:

```
data: { review_id: id,
        comment: comment,
        luser_id: luser_id
      },
```

Comment: sorry...i am already using..encodeURI for comment...like this..var comment = encodeURI($(this).val());

Comment: Where are you seeing the extra characters? In the paragraph that the success function displays?

Comment: success function is not called..when i entered double question mark...extra characters are displaying in comments...please help

Comment: Then where is it printing out what you showed in the question?

Comment: when i refresh page comments are showed with extra characters....jQuery110205576835575724747_1411410901236

Comment: I suspect the problem is in the controller. I've never heard of jQuery doing anything special with `??` in the AJAX parameter.

Comment: I have checked everything...whenever i put double question mark..success is not calling but value is inserted to database..with..weird text...i have checked with firebug it doesn't show any error...there is simple code in controller and model..and it correctly returning value(id in my case)...but success is not calling.